# How to store COUNT(*) result in variable in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to store the result of `COUNT(*)` in a variable and use it later for an `if` statement. Here is my current code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appointment WHERE date = '$date_convert' and appointment_time = '$appointment_time'");

if ($query >= '1') {
    echo "Dont Continue";
}
else{
    echo "Continue";
}
```

Comment: `$query` is a result object, not a string. Fetch it, then access the value from the index. You also should use an alias in the query so the index is easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object. You need to first get the row and then you can compare the column value. To get a row from the result, call `->fetch_assoc();` on it. ([Docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php))

Your code should look like this:

```
// Execute the query
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM appointment WHERE date = '$date_convert' and appointment_time = '$appointment_time'");

// Since there will always be exactly 1 row, fetch it.
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($row['count'] >= 1) {
    echo "Dont Continue";
}
else {
    echo "Continue";
}
```

Additionally, I gave your `count()` column a name, so that it can be accessed even when the default column name for count changes. And I changed the comparison so that you compare two integers (no casting involved).